# Listening to IOKit events with Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, macos

This is my first program in Swift/Xcode. The full source code and xcode project is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw).

The part I would like reviewed is `IOKeyEventMonitor.swift`.

```
//Copyright [2016] Jean Helou
//
//Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//limitations under the License.
import Foundation
import Carbon
import IOKit
import IOKit.usb
import IOKit.hid


struct IOKeyEventMonitorContext {
  var lastSeenSender: String
  init(lastSeenSender: String) {
    self.lastSeenSender = lastSeenSender
  }
}

class IOKeyEventMonitor {
  private
  let hidManager: IOHIDManager
  let notificationCenter: CFNotificationCenter
  let match: CFMutableDictionary

  var lastActiveKeyboard: String = ""
  var kb2is: [String: TISInputSource] = [String: TISInputSource]()


  private class func createDeviceMatchingDictionary( usagePage: Int, usage: Int) -> CFMutableDictionary {
    let dict = [
      kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey: usage,
      kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey: usagePage
    ] as NSDictionary

    return dict.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary;
  }

  init? ( usagePage: Int, usage: Int) {
    hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone));
    notificationCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();
    match = IOKeyEventMonitor.createDeviceMatchingDictionary(usagePage: usagePage, usage: usage);
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching( hidManager, match);
  }

  deinit {
    // FIXME find out how to pass nil as an IOKit.IOHIDValueCallback to unregister the callback
    let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque());
    //IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, nil , context);
    CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(notificationCenter, context, CFNotificationName(kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged), nil);
  }

  func restoreInputSource(keyboard: String) -> Void {
    if let targetIs = kb2is[keyboard] {
      //print("set input source to \(targetIs) for keyboard \(keyboard)");
      TISSelectInputSource(targetIs)
    } else {
      self.storeInputSource(keyboard: keyboard);
    }
  }

  func storeInputSource(keyboard: String) -> Void {
    let currentSource: TISInputSource = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeUnretainedValue();
    kb2is[keyboard] = currentSource;
  }

  func onInputSourceChanged() -> Void {
    self.storeInputSource(keyboard: self.lastActiveKeyboard);
  }

  func onKeyboardEvent(keyboard: String) -> Void {
    if(self.lastActiveKeyboard != keyboard) {
      //print("Active keyboard changed from \(self.lastActiveKeyboard) to \(keyboard)");
      self.restoreInputSource(keyboard: keyboard);
      self.lastActiveKeyboard = keyboard;
    }
  }


  func start() -> Void {
    let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque());
    let myHIDKeyboardCallback: IOHIDValueCallback = {
      (context, ioreturn, sender, value) in
      let selfPtr = Unmanaged<IOKeyEventMonitor>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue();
      let senderDevice = Unmanaged<IOHIDDevice>.fromOpaque(sender!).takeUnretainedValue();

      let vendorId = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice, kIOHIDVendorIDKey as CFString));
      let productId = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice, kIOHIDProductIDKey as CFString));
      let product = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice, kIOHIDProductKey as CFString));
      let keyboard = "\(product)[\(vendorId)-\(productId)]";
      selfPtr.onKeyboardEvent(keyboard: keyboard);

    }
    let inputSourceChanged: CFNotificationCallback = {
      (center, observer, name, notif, userInfo) in
      let selfPtr = Unmanaged<IOKeyEventMonitor>.fromOpaque(observer!).takeUnretainedValue();
      selfPtr.onInputSourceChanged()
    }

    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(notificationCenter,
                                    context, inputSourceChanged,
                                    kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged, nil,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately);


    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, myHIDKeyboardCallback, context);
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop( hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode!.rawValue);
    IOHIDManagerOpen( hidManager, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone));
  }

}
```

How would you rewrite this to be idiomatic Swift? How can I improve the `start()` function in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you write better code than many (myself probably included) that have been Swifting for a while. So, for your first program, it's impressive.

However, code is kinda bunched up (for my taste), perhaps a few more blank lines? Also, runs way too far out in a few places... See how I "wrapped" those long function prams.

Also, some nitpicks I found:

parenthesis consistency. `( x) (x) ( x )`

func declaration spacing inconsistency:

```
func x(){}

func y() {}


func z() {}
```

forgot `:` in `fixme`

using `;`

using `-> Void`

no space after `//`

using `self` when not in a closure on initializer

used `private` on its own line, not sure if you wanted all members private or just the first field. (First field in class)

`if(self.lastActiveKeyboard != keyboard)` no space in between? And parenthesis can be saved for more complicated statements:
`if lastActiveKeyboard != keyboard {`

no `// MARK:` for easy navigation. I added one so you can quickly hop between your properties + initializers and your functions, since you already separated them out into halves :) which is good! Make a keyboard shortcut for `Show Document Items` if you havent already, and you will see all of your `FIXME:` and `MARK:` in a list

Missed one procedural style... used `storeInputSource` before it was declared... (inside `restore`) NOTE: this isn't "required" but it helps your logic flow (to yourself and readers) but sometimes you will have to break this depending on your style.

closures typically inline up to `in`, and you have inconsistencies with this regardless. I would only newline it if you go past the 90th column.

inconsistent closing brace `}` (sometimes have empty line, sometimes no space)

no comments or documentation (will you understand this code a month from now? What about people that might look at it? Or people you ask for help with it?)

So mostly nitpicks. Nothing particularly un-swifty about this code. For no particular reason, I want to make sure you know about `guard` because you do have one `if let` statement in there, but it's a good use of `if let`. Just wanted to make sure you knew about guard too.

Here is my quick-redraft of your code, and I added my personal touch to `start()` since you asked :P

```
// Copyright [2016] Jean Helou
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

import Foundation
import Carbon
import IOKit
import IOKit.usb
import IOKit.hid


struct IOKeyEventMonitorContext {
  var lastSeenSender: String
  init(lastSeenSender: String) {
    self.lastSeenSender = lastSeenSender
  }
}

class IOKeyEventMonitor {
  private let hidManager: IOHIDManager

  let notificationCenter: CFNotificationCenter
  let match: CFMutableDictionary

  var lastActiveKeyboard: String = ""
  var kb2is: [String: TISInputSource] = [String: TISInputSource]()

  private class func createDeviceMatchingDictionary(usagePage: Int, usage: Int) -> CFMutableDictionary {
    let dict = [
      kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey: usage,
      kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey: usagePage
    ] as NSDictionary

    return dict.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
  }

  init? (usagePage: Int, usage: Int) {
    hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))
    notificationCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter()
    match = IOKeyEventMonitor.createDeviceMatchingDictionary(usagePage: usagePage, usage: usage)
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching( hidManager, match)
  }

  deinit {
    // FIXME: Find out how to pass nil as an IOKit.IOHIDValueCallback to unregister the callback
    let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
    // IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, nil , context)
    CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(notificationCenter,
                                       context,
                                       CFNotificationName(kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged),
                                       nil)
  }

// MARK: - Funcs:

  func storeInputSource(keyboard: String) {
    let currentSource: TISInputSource = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeUnretainedValue();
    kb2is[keyboard] = currentSource
  }

  func restoreInputSource(keyboard: String) {
    if let targetIs = kb2is[keyboard] {
      // print("set input source to \(targetIs) for keyboard \(keyboard)")
      TISSelectInputSource(targetIs)
    } else {
      storeInputSource(keyboard: keyboard)
    }
  }

  func onInputSourceChanged() {
    storeInputSource(keyboard: self.lastActiveKeyboard);
  }

  func onKeyboardEvent(keyboard: String) {
    if lastActiveKeyboard != keyboard {
      // print("Active keyboard changed from \(self.lastActiveKeyboard) to \(keyboard)")
      restoreInputSource(keyboard: keyboard)
      lastActiveKeyboard = keyboard
    }
  }

  func start() {
    let context = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    let myHIDKeyboardCallback: IOHIDValueCallback = { (context, ioreturn, sender, value) in

      let
      selfPtr      = Unmanaged<IOKeyEventMonitor>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue(),

      senderDevice = Unmanaged<IOHIDDevice>.fromOpaque(sender!).takeUnretainedValue(),

      vendorId     = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice,
                                                               kIOHIDVendorIDKey  as CFString)),
      productId    = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice,
                                                               kIOHIDProductIDKey as CFString)),
      product      = String(describing: IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(senderDevice,
                                                               kIOHIDProductKey   as CFString)),
      keyboard     = "\(product)[\(vendorId)-\(productId)]"

      selfPtr.onKeyboardEvent(keyboard: keyboard)
    }

    let inputSourceChanged: CFNotificationCallback = { (center, observer, name, notif, userInfo) in
      let selfPtr = Unmanaged<IOKeyEventMonitor>.fromOpaque(observer!).takeUnretainedValue()
      selfPtr.onInputSourceChanged()
    }

    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(notificationCenter,
                                    context,
                                    inputSourceChanged,
                                    kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged,
                                    nil,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately)

    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(hidManager, myHIDKeyboardCallback, context)
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode!.rawValue)
    IOHIDManagerOpen(hidManager, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))
  }
}
```

---

NOTE:
I couldn't compile this due to the imports, so I may have deleted a few too many `self` perhaps in a closure, but I don't think that I did...

The only other thing I would do would be to `typealias` some of those ridiculously long IO / Carbon types, which would help keep things closer to the left, and make chaining somewhat readable.. For example,

```
typealias CFNCGDC = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter
// Or:
typealias CFNCGetDistCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter
// Or if it is a function:
extension CrazyCarbonClass {
  public func CFNSShortFunc(/* all the prams */) {
    CFNotificationCenterLongAsHellFunc(/* prams */)
  }
}
```

But that is just my preference.

Comment: Hi thanks for the review :) I come from java where IDEs format and indent the code consistently. I tried using the format feature of xcode but it's not as powerful. Since I posted the review I found and used swimat to solve all these. regarding private I did want all the instance variable to be private as I see no reason to expose them. I'll dig in the rest of the remarks to get a better grasp :)

Comment: @jean Yes, Xcode does suck in many regards.. Jetbrains does have one for Swift though, AppCode, but it's Swift support isn't quite as good as it's Java support yet... I use it for formatting / folding alongside Xcode :)

Comment: oh, also, if you do check out AppCode, it was only the latest EAP that introduced a bunch of new Swift features.. so I'd pick that one up over the stable channel.

Comment: I haven't applied everything from your review (yet) but thanks again for taking the time.